# Using Future with ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, executorservice

I need to execute two tasks in parallel and wait for them to complete. Also I need the result from the second task, for that I am using `Future`.

My question is that DO I need `executor.awaitTermination` to join the tasks or `Future.get()` will take care of it. Also is there a better way to achieve this with Java 8?

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test();
        System.out.println("Exiting Main");
    }

    public static void test() {
        System.out.println("In Test");
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        executor.submit(() -> {
            for(int i = 0 ; i< 5 ; i++) {
                System.out.print("["+i+"]");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        });

        Future<String> result = executor.submit(() -> {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0 ; i< 10 ; i++) {
                System.out.print("("+i+")");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                builder.append(i);
            }
            return builder.toString();
        });

        System.out.println("shutdown");
        executor.shutdown();
        // DO I need this code : START
        System.out.println("awaitTermination");
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        // DO I need this code : END
        System.out.println("Getting result");
        try {
            System.out.println(result.get());
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (ExecutionException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        System.out.println("Exiting Test");
    }

}
```

OUTPUT with **awaitTermination**:

```
In Test
[0]shutdown
(0)awaitTermination
[1](1)[2](2)[3](3)[4](4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)Getting result
0123456789
Exiting Test
Exiting Main
```

OUTPUT without **awaitTermination**:

```
In Test
[0]shutdown
Getting result
(0)[1](1)[2](2)[3](3)[4](4)(5)(6)(7)(8)(9)0123456789
Exiting Test
Exiting Main
```

Comment: Of course, you have to call `get()` on *both* futures to join them. Currently, you not even keep the first task’s future…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `get` javadoc:

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

`get` will wait for the second task only.

From the `awaitTermination` javadoc:

> Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first.

`awaitTermination` will wait for all tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `CompletableFuture` API

You can run a process async like follow:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( () -> { ... } );
```

It returns a future, and you can add a callback which will be called when process is finished and result is available.

For example:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> { 
     // Here compute your string
     return "something";
} ).thenAccept( result -> {
     // Here do something with result (ie the computed string)
} );
```

Note that this statement uses internally the `ForkJoinPool#commonPool()` to execute the process async, but you can also call this statement with your own `ExecutorService` if you want. In both case, in order to be sure not exiting before tasks are completed, you need to call either `get()` (which is blocking) on each future of submitted tasks, or wait for the executor to shutdown.

Comment: Apparently his 2 tasks are independent so there is no real advantage in using `CompletableFuture` here.